# Find records updated within hour timeframe from creation of new record

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, time

Let's say I have records that are created for every entry a user creates. We will call these documents. They have a **CreatedWhen** column.

Let's also state that documents can be updated changing their timestamp. A column known as **UpdatedOn**.

The **UpdatedOn** column has an initial timestamp that is the same as CreatedOn for new document creation, unless they saved it before exiting.

Now, someone wants to know what documents were updated 2 hours prior to the creation of a new document.

Here was my attempt, and I can't figure out why it's not working.

EDIT: The times I get back are not correct.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN (d2.UpdatedOn IS NOT NULL)
         THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by d2.DocumentID, d2.DocumentName, d2.CreatedWhen --sequence grouping
                                     order by d2.UpdatedOn desc) --get earliest dates
         ELSE 0
    END as SeqNum,
    d.DocumentName,
    d.CreatedWhen
    d2.DocumentName as [DocUpdatedWithin2HR],
    d2.UpdatedOn
Into #temp
FROM Documents d
JOIN Documents d2 ON d.DocumentID = d2.DocumentID
WHERE d2.UpdatedOn BETWEEN DATEADD(Hour,-2,d.CreatedWhen) --2 hours prior, 1 hour window
                      AND DATEADD(Second,-1,(DATEADD(Hour,-1,d.CreatedWhen))) --1 second shy of an hour

select distinct
    DocumentName,
    CreatedWhen,
    DocUpdatedWithin2HR, --xml path this column later
    UpdatedOn
from #temp where rn = 1 order by 1,3
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a little? You want to know what documents has been updated within 2 hours. Right?

Comment: Describe how it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

The JOIN needs the DocumentID. I'm surprised you didn't get a syntax error. Update the JOIN to `JOIN Documents d2 ON d.DocumentID = d2.DocumentID`

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer.

Comment: I wish I was at that reputation to comment. Almost.